# Swift - confirm when changing view

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uialertview

I have a ViewController that is embedded both in Tab Bar Controller and in Navigation Controller. It has a role of a game/quiz:

[image]

I want a user to confirm everytime if he wants to quit the game in progress whenever he tries to change view (change tab, click "Back" or just exit app).

So I guess my question is: Where should I place my `UIAlertController` in order to have it working the way described?

Comment: so `addTarget` action to that button then set your UIAlertController

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the delegates for both the `UITabBarController` and the `UINavigationBar`, `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationBarDelegate` respectively.

For the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` implement:

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    // alert here, don't go back unless user confirms
}
```

For the `UINavigationBarDelegate` implement:

```
func navigationBar(navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPopItem item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool {
    // alert here, don't go back unless user confirms
}
```

Note: The `UINavigationBar` is a property of your `UINavigationController` - you can become the delegate by `navigationController.navigationBar.delegate = self;`

Comment: Hi, thanks, this was actually pretty useful. I can't get this working though. `shouldPopItem` returns immediately and doesn't even wait for `UIAlertController` response. So I can pop view controller after user confirmation, but navigation bar item doesn't get popped. Do you know maybe how to solve this, @Carter?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the navigation bar doesn't get popped. After the user confirms you can tell your UINavigationController to pop, which should update the Bar as well.

Comment: It does update the bar correctly, but the View Controller (below navigation bar) doesn't pop to the previous View on the navigation stack, even if I try to run `self.popViewControllerAnimated` method.

Comment: I looked through SO a bit more and it seems that the only way to do it, is to hide "Back" button and to implement custom navigation bar item that would function as "Back" but actually can show alert box before popping the View controller.

Comment: Following these [instructions](https://smallduck.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/intercepting-uinavigationcontroller/) it looks like you can use the delegate. I'm guessing that it is called when you call `self.popViewControllerAnimated`, so you'll have to have some logic that returns `true` when you want to pop and `false` otherwise.